# How to publish cloudwatch values which have a sampleCount of 0?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We've been struggling for some time to properly publish internal metrics into [Amazon's CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) service.  We have a number of different types of internal metrics that we map into [CloudWatch's `MetricDatum` class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/model/MetricDatum.html) and publish.

Each of the `MetricDatum` instances has a `double value` and also a `StatisticSet` which accepts a `sampleCount`, `sum`, and `minimum`/`maximum` values.  For counters such as a Httpd 200 page counter, it is more appropriate to use the `StatisticSet` and set the `sampleCount` and the `sum` to the value of the counter.  If you look at the ELB stats for example, that is what Amazon does to publish them.  This makes the sum, average and other graph views work correctly when you are graphing the result.

The problem is when the value of the counter is 0 because CloudWatch does not allow you to publish a `StatisticSet` with a `sampleCount` of 0.  What ELB does is to not publish anything for that period which creates holes in the graph.  This is a pain because you get `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` warnings when the counter is 0 for the time period.  If you have notifications on `ERROR` and want to know when you transition back to `OK`, the `INSUFFICIENT_DATA to OK` alerts will keep you up *all* night.

> You have 1 alarm in INSUFFICIENT DATA state in US East (N. Virginia) region.

**Question:** How do I properly publish CloudWatch metrics so that you don't see the `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` warnings but still use the `sampleCount` with metrics that have a value of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you cannot publish a `StatisticSet` with a `sampleCount` of 0, you *can* publish it with an extremely small `sampleCount` since it is a `double`.   We have found that a `sampleCount` of `0.000000001` seems to give the appearance of 0 on the graphs but it still fills in the holes in the graph appropriately and does not cause the `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` alarms to happen.

```
double sampleCount = numSamples;
// our values come in as value and numSamples but StatisticSet wants a sum
double sum = value * numSamples;
if (numSamples == 0) {
    // special case here, CloudWatch does not allow a 0 sample count so we have to
    // set it to be slightly more
    sampleCount = 0.000000001D;
    // but sum can be 0
}
StatisticSet statisticSet =
    new StatisticSet().withMinimum(min)
            .withMaximum(max)
            .withSampleCount(sampleCount)
            .withSum(sum);
```

As an aside, I've coded some of this logic into my [SimpleMetrics library](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplemetrics/) which is designed to easily track and publish metrics.

Comment: I'm confused. If the min, max, and sum are all the same (zero reportable events in this interval/sample/data point), then I'd think any non-zero sample count would give the same average. Could you not just as well use 1.0? Are you wanting to plot cumulative events vs time or a time derivative (e.g. #events/second)?

Comment: We were looking at more than average however.  We wanted didn't want to affect our min/max or other graphs with an invalid sample count.  We didn't want to in effect publish a value of 0 with a single sample which may have been grossly incorrect @JayCarlton.